# Specifying a specific source address for an Apache forward proxy

Tags: apache-2.4, ip-address

The [Apache 2.4 new features](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/new_features_2_4.html) page says: "The source address used for proxy requests is now configurable."

I can't find out how. The words "Source address" aren't mentioned on the [2.4 mod_proxy page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html)....

Googling suggests ProxySourceAddress as a relevant parameter, but the discussion seems to be about a patch to 2.2 not what was done in 2.4...

So can someone point me at the documentation I may have missed?

Answer (score 1):

`ProxySourceAddress` is correct.  See [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxysourceaddress).

Comment: Thanks. Aargh. I searched for "source address" with a space, and for some reason it didn't come up in the google searches I did.